# Change web form elements if number changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a web form which will add in questions based on the number that the user ticks (ie in the drop down box they enter that they have 5 children, it add in questions for each of those 5 children.)

I can get it to dynamically add in the required number of fields when you first click it, but how would I go about making it update if they chose a different number of children later?

I have my function set out as below:

**HTML**

```
<label for="kids" class="kidsno">Number of children</label>
<select type="number" id="kids" class="kidsno" required onchange="KidsInfo()">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function KidsInfo() { 
    var num = $('#kids').val(); 
       inum = parseInt(num); 
       var $name = $('<ul class="flex-outer"> <li> <label for="kidfirst">First Name *</label><input type="text"' + 
                    ' id="kidfirst" name="kidfirst" placeholder="Enter first name here" required></li> ' + 
                    ' <li> <label for="kidlast">Last Name *</label><input type="text"id="kidlast" name="kidlast" ' + 
                    ' placeholder="Enter last name here" required></li> ') 
       var $age = $('<ul class="flex-outer"><li> <label for="childDOB">Date of Birth *</label>' + 
                    ' <input type="date" id="ChildDOB" name="dateofbirth"> </li><li><label for="kidgen">Gender *</label>' + 
                    '   <input list="gender" id="gen" name="gender" placeholder="Enter or select gender here" required> ' + 
                    '<datalist id="gender"><option value="Male"><option value="Female"> <option value="Prefer not to say"> </datalist></li><br/>') 
        
       $("<legend>Children's Information</legend>").appendTo($(".children")); 
        
    for (i=0; i < inum; i++) { 
        
        $name.add($age).clone().appendTo($(".children")); 
    } 
    $("</ul>").appendTo($(".children")); 
}
```

Comment: Change the loop condition to stop at (current select value minus current row count), so that it adds only the number of new rows required. If the (select value minus row count) is negative then remove that number of items from the end (maybe prompt the user to see if that is OK if they've already entered data in the fields to be removed). Note that your current code creates invalid HTML because you'll have duplicate element IDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is for one `onchange` method to handle everything: both increases *and* decreases to the number of child records needed.

I'm guessing at your form structure, but the method below should be the right idea. It adds/removes child records to the DOM as needed, and doesn't overwrite existing ones (losing input data) if they will still show. It also uses a `.show`/`.hide` to handle updates back to zero, and an outer container for child input data pre-exists in the form.

```js
function KidsInfo() { 
    var num = $('#kids').val(); 
       inum = parseInt(num); 
       var $name = $('<ul class="flex-outer"> <li> <label for="kidfirst">First Name *</label><input type="text"' + 
                    ' id="kidfirst" name="kidfirst" placeholder="Enter first name here" required></li> ' + 
                    ' <li> <label for="kidlast">Last Name *</label><input type="text"id="kidlast" name="kidlast" ' + 
                    ' placeholder="Enter last name here" required></li> ');
       var $age = $('<ul class="flex-outer"><li> <label for="childDOB">Date of Birth *</label>' + 
                    ' <input type="date" id="ChildDOB" name="dateofbirth"> </li><li><label for="kidgen">Gender *</label>' + 
                    '   <input list="gender" id="gen" name="gender" placeholder="Enter or select gender here" required> ' + 
                    '<datalist id="gender"><option value="Male"><option value="Female"> <option value="Prefer not to say"> </datalist></li><br/>');
      var $childform = $('<div class="childdata"></div>').append($name).append($age);
      
      // first remove extra records if they are there
      $('.childdata').each(function(i, elem) {
          if (i >= inum) {
              $(elem).remove();
          }
      });
      
      // now add records if necessary
      var existing = $('.childdata').length;
      for (var i = existing; i < inum; i++) {
          $('.children').append($childform.clone());
      }
      
      // now show/hide as appropriate
      if (inum > 0) {
          $('.children').show();
      } else {
          $('.children').hide();
      }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="kids" class="kidsno">Number of children</label>
<select type="number" id="kids" class="kidsno" required onchange="KidsInfo()">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
</select>

<div class="children" style="display: none;">
    <legend>Children's Information</legend>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could rebuild the `.children`'s content each time number of kids is changed:

```
var name_template = '<ul class="flex-outer"> <li> <label for="kidfirst">First Name *</label><input type="text"' + 
                    ' id="kidfirst" name="kidfirst" placeholder="Enter first name here" required></li> ' + 
                    ' <li> <label for="kidlast">Last Name *</label><input type="text"id="kidlast" name="kidlast" ' + 
                    ' placeholder="Enter last name here" required></li>';

var age_template = '<ul class="flex-outer"><li> <label for="childDOB">Date of Birth *</label>' + 
                    ' <input type="date" id="ChildDOB" name="dateofbirth"> </li><li><label for="kidgen">Gender *</label>' + 
                    '   <input list="gender" id="gen" name="gender" placeholder="Enter or select gender here" required> ' + 
                    '<datalist id="gender"><option value="Male"><option value="Female"> <option value="Prefer not to say"> </datalist></li><br/>'

var legend_template = "<legend>Children's Information</legend>"

function KidsInfo() { 
    var num = $('#kids').val(); 
    inum = parseInt(num);
    var html = ''
    for (i=0; i < inum; i++) { 
        html += '<ul class="flex-outer">'
        html += name_template
        html += age_template
        html += legend_template
        html += '</ul>'
    }
    $(".children").html(html)
}
```

Comment: Ah, right. Didn't think of that. Well your approach is def. better.